# How can pyomo & ipopt calculate different results each time

Tags: python, pyomo, np, ipopt

I am using `pyomo` and `ipopt` to solve a nonlinear problem involving over 100 variables. I don't know too much math to know what the options in ipopt mean.

If my conditions are set relatively loosely, I find that every time my program is restarted, the results are far different from the last, and even if they are `optimal`, only some of them are satisfactory to me. I've tried to make the constraints a little bit tighter, but that also reduces the probability that I'm going to get a valid result.

So my approach is to loop `solver.solve` multiple times, storing the appropriate result into a file and then constrainting it. If I put `model.cons = ConstraintList()` into the loop, the program is running too slow; If I just put `solver.solve(...)` in the loop, as long as I don't run the program again, I'll get almost the same solution no matter how many times I loop through it.

I am not sure whether this problem is about `pyomo` or `ipopt`. I hope anyone can help me so that I can get different solutions in each cycle, thank you.

Here is my code:

```
# Create model is extremly slow, can't bear it in loop
model = ConcreteModel()

model.x = Var(range(n),range(n),[0,1],within=NonNegativeIntegers)
model.tolerance = Param(initialize=s_tolerance, mutable=True)

# Some constraints
model.cons = ConstraintList()
for j in range(n):
    model.cons.add(sum(model.x[i,j,0] for i in range(n)) == data[j][3])
    model.cons.add(sum(model.x[i,j,1] for i in range(n)) == data[j][4])

# Get almost the same solutions with these code
while True:
    # Not work for random solution
    seed = random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5)
    model.tolerance.set_value(seed + s_tolerance)

    solver = SolverFactory('ipopt', keepfiles=False)
    results = solver.solve(model, tee=False, symbolic_solver_labels=False, options={'max_iter':2000})
    
    if good_result(results):
        break
```

Comment: You don't have an objective function defined in your model ... sooooo, any valid solution is "optimal".  Further, the model parameter `tolerance` is not used for anything... ??

Comment: And... the portion of the model you describe with the constraints is linear so `ipopt` is not an appropriate solver for this.

Comment: To add to the first comment: If your problem has many optimal solutions and you run Ipopt with different tolerances several times (that's my guess what model.tolerance is about), then you can get different optimal solutions. There is no way how Ipopt would know that to you, some of them are better than others.